Flow Error: DUPLICATE_VALUE in Case After-Save Flow When Creating CaseTeamMember Records
I am encountering an issue with a Flow in Salesforce, specifically an autolaunched "Case After-Save Flow." The flow is designed to add CaseTeamMember records to a Case based on certain conditions. However, I am receiving a DUPLICATE_VALUE error when the flow attempts to create CaseTeamMember records.
Error Context
The error occurs when the flow tries to create records in the CaseTeamMember object. Below are the relevant steps in the flow:
Get PAC Staff: Successfully finds HealthcarePractitionerFacility records.
Loop through PAC Staff: Adds each Practitioner.User_Record__c to CaseTeamMember collection if the user is active.
Get Sales TeamRole: Finds CaseTeamRole records successfully.
Add Sales Rep as Staff: Adds Sales Rep to CaseTeamMember collection.
Create Case Team: Tries to create CaseTeamMember records, fails due to duplicate values.
Somehow the flow assigns two roles on one user: CREATE RECORDS: Create Case Team
Create CaseTeamMember records using the values that are stored in {!CaseTeamForInsert}.
Variable Values
[ParentId=500Uy00000ETWSlIAP,MemberId=005Uy00000GGxhRIAT,TeamRoleId=0B78c000000bloHCAQ]
[ParentId=500Uy00000ETWSlIAP,MemberId=0058c00000DB0rdAAD,TeamRoleId=0B78c000000bloHCAQ]
[ParentId=500Uy00000ETWSlIAP,MemberId=0058c00000DAeJUAA1,TeamRoleId=0B78c000000bloHCAQ]
[ParentId=500Uy00000ETWSlIAP,MemberId=0058c00000DB0rdAAD,TeamRoleId=0B78c000000wkDWCAY]
Result
Failed to create records.
I think this is where the issue is. Any thoughts? Below is the full generated error:
$Record = Case (500Uy00000ETWSlIAP)
DECISION: Referring Acct/Contact Notes Post?
Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met: YesNotesPost
Outcome conditions:
1. {!ISNEW} (true) Equals true
2. {!$Record.ReferringPractitioner__c} (0038c00003Leub2AAB) Is null false
3. {!$Record.ReferringPractitioner__r.Notes__c} (null) Is null false
4. {!$Record.ReferringProvider__c} (0018c00002rgFigAAE) Is null false
5. {!$Record.ReferringProvider__r.Notes__c} (null) Is null false
Logic: Advanced Logic (1 AND ((2 AND 3) OR (4 AND 5)))

Default outcome executed.

DECISION: Recalculate Case Rollups?
Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met: YesClosedChanged
Outcome conditions:
1. {!$Record.IsClosed} (false) Is changed true
2. {!$Record.OwnerId} (00G8c000006eu5dEAA) Starts with 005
3. {!$Record.OwnerId} (00G8c000006eu5dEAA) Is changed true
Logic: Advanced Logic ((1 AND 2) OR 3)

Default outcome executed.

DECISION: Facility Changed?
Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met: YesClearPACs
Outcome conditions:
1. {!$Record.Healthcare_Facility__c} (0kl8c000000kAo3AAE) Is null false
2. {!$Record.Healthcare_Facility__c} (0kl8c000000kAo3AAE) Is changed true
3. {!$Record__Prior.Healthcare_Facility__c} (null) Is null false
4. {!$Record.HasCaseTeam__c} (false) Equals true
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)

Default outcome executed.

DECISION: Has Case Team?
Skipped this outcome because its conditions weren't met: Yes
Outcome conditions:
{!$Record.HasCaseTeam__c} (false) Equals true
All conditions must be true (AND)

Default outcome executed.

GET RECORDS: Get PAC staff
Find all HealthcarePractitionerFacility records where:
HealthcareFacilityId Equals {!$Record.Healthcare_Facility__c} (0kl8c000000kAo3AAE)
AND Role__c Contains PAC
AND IsActive Equals true
Sort records by: Role__c (Ascending)
Store the values of these fields in GetPACStaff: PractitionerId, Id
Result
Successfully found records.

DECISION: Found PAC Staff?
Outcome executed: YesFoundPACTop
Outcome conditions:
{!GetPACStaff} ([HealthcarePractitionerFacility (0bSUy00000001grMAA),HealthcarePractitionerFacility (0bS8c000000oNMOEA2),HealthcarePractitionerFacility (0bS8c0000010zZHEAY)]) Is null false
All conditions must be true (AND)

GET RECORDS: Get PAC TeamRole
Find all CaseTeamRole records where:
Name Equals PAC
Store the values of these fields in Get_PAC_TeamRole: Id
Result
Successfully found records.

LOOP: Loop PAC Staff
Loop Through: [0bSUy00000001grMAA,0bS8c000000oNMOEA2,0bS8c0000010zZHEAY]
Iteration: 0
Current iteration item: 0bSUy00000001grMAA

DECISION: Has User?
Outcome executed: YesHasEmailPAC
Outcome conditions:
1. {!Loop_PAC_Staff.Practitioner.User_Record__c} (005Uy00000GGxhRIAT) Is null false
2. {!Loop_PAC_Staff.Practitioner.User_Record__r.IsActive} (true) Equals true
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)

ASSIGNMENT: Add to Case Team Collection
{!CaseTeamMember.ParentId} Equals {!$Record.Id}
{!CaseTeamMember.MemberId} Equals {!Loop_PAC_Staff.Practitioner.User_Record__c}
{!CaseTeamMember.TeamRoleId} Equals {!Get_PAC_TeamRole.Id}
{!CaseTeamForInsert} Add {!CaseTeamMember}
Result
{!CaseTeamMember.TeamRoleId} = "0B78c000000bloHCAQ"
{!CaseTeamMember.MemberId} = "005Uy00000GGxhRIAT"
{!CaseTeamForInsert} = "[CaseTeamMember (No ID)]"
{!CaseTeamMember.ParentId} = "500Uy00000ETWSlIAP"

LOOP: Loop PAC Staff
Loop Through: [0bSUy00000001grMAA,0bS8c000000oNMOEA2,0bS8c0000010zZHEAY]
Iteration: 1
Current iteration item: 0bS8c000000oNMOEA2

DECISION: Has User?
Outcome executed: YesHasEmailPAC
Outcome conditions:
1. {!Loop_PAC_Staff.Practitioner.User_Record__c} (0058c00000DB0rdAAD) Is null false
2. {!Loop_PAC_Staff.Practitioner.User_Record__r.IsActive} (true) Equals true
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)

ASSIGNMENT: Add to Case Team Collection
{!CaseTeamMember.ParentId} Equals {!$Record.Id}
{!CaseTeamMember.MemberId} Equals {!Loop_PAC_Staff.Practitioner.User_Record__c}
{!CaseTeamMember.TeamRoleId} Equals {!Get_PAC_TeamRole.Id}
{!CaseTeamForInsert} Add {!CaseTeamMember}
Result
{!CaseTeamMember.TeamRoleId} = "0B78c000000bloHCAQ"
{!CaseTeamMember.MemberId} = "0058c00000DB0rdAAD"
{!CaseTeamForInsert} = "[CaseTeamMember (No ID),CaseTeamMember (No ID)]"
{!CaseTeamMember.ParentId} = "500Uy00000ETWSlIAP"

LOOP: Loop PAC Staff
Loop Through: [0bSUy00000001grMAA,0bS8c000000oNMOEA2,0bS8c0000010zZHEAY]
Iteration: 2
Current iteration item: 0bS8c0000010zZHEAY

DECISION: Has User?
Outcome executed: YesHasEmailPAC
Outcome conditions:
1. {!Loop_PAC_Staff.Practitioner.User_Record__c} (0058c00000DAeJUAA1) Is null false
2. {!Loop_PAC_Staff.Practitioner.User_Record__r.IsActive} (true) Equals true
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)

ASSIGNMENT: Add to Case Team Collection
{!CaseTeamMember.ParentId} Equals {!$Record.Id}
{!CaseTeamMember.MemberId} Equals {!Loop_PAC_Staff.Practitioner.User_Record__c}
{!CaseTeamMember.TeamRoleId} Equals {!Get_PAC_TeamRole.Id}
{!CaseTeamForInsert} Add {!CaseTeamMember}
Result
{!CaseTeamMember.TeamRoleId} = "0B78c000000bloHCAQ"
{!CaseTeamMember.MemberId} = "0058c00000DAeJUAA1"
{!CaseTeamForInsert} = "[CaseTeamMember (No ID),CaseTeamMember (No ID),CaseTeamMember (No ID)]"
{!CaseTeamMember.ParentId} = "500Uy00000ETWSlIAP"

LOOP: Loop PAC Staff
End Loop.

DECISION: Has Sales Rep?
Outcome executed: YesHasSalesRep
Outcome conditions:
1. {!$Record.Referral__c} (006Uy000009QAHtIAO) Is null false
2. {!$Record.Referral__r.OwnerId} (0058c00000DB0rdAAD) Starts with 005
3. {!$Record.Referral__r.Owner.IsActive} (true) Equals true
Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)

GET RECORDS: Get Sales TeamRole
Find all CaseTeamRole records where:
Name Equals Sales
Store the values of these fields in Get_Sales_TeamRole: Id
Result
Successfully found records.

ASSIGNMENT: Add Sales Rep as Staff
{!CaseTeamMember.ParentId} Equals {!$Record.Id}
{!CaseTeamMember.MemberId} Equals {!$Record.Referral__r.OwnerId}
{!CaseTeamMember.TeamRoleId} Equals {!Get_Sales_TeamRole.Id}
{!CaseTeamForInsert} Add {!CaseTeamMember}
Result
{!CaseTeamMember.TeamRoleId} = "0B78c000000wkDWCAY"
{!CaseTeamMember.MemberId} = "0058c00000DB0rdAAD"
{!CaseTeamForInsert} = "[CaseTeamMember (No ID),CaseTeamMember (No ID),CaseTeamMember (No ID),CaseTeamMember (No ID)]"
{!CaseTeamMember.ParentId} = "500Uy00000ETWSlIAP"

CREATE RECORDS: Create Case Team
Create CaseTeamMember records using the values that are stored in {!CaseTeamForInsert}.
Variable Values
[ParentId=500Uy00000ETWSlIAP,MemberId=005Uy00000GGxhRIAT,TeamRoleId=0B78c000000bloHCAQ]
[ParentId=500Uy00000ETWSlIAP,MemberId=0058c00000DB0rdAAD,TeamRoleId=0B78c000000bloHCAQ]
[ParentId=500Uy00000ETWSlIAP,MemberId=0058c00000DAeJUAA1,TeamRoleId=0B78c000000bloHCAQ]
[ParentId=500Uy00000ETWSlIAP,MemberId=0058c00000DB0rdAAD,TeamRoleId=0B78c000000wkDWCAY]
Result
Failed to create records.

Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: DUPLICATE_VALUE: duplicate value found: duplicates value on record with id: . You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

